# Two Independent Random Variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

To show that two random variable $X$ and $Y$ (for discrete case) are not independent, is it suffices to show that $P(X=x|Y=y)\neq P(X=x)$ for a certain $x$ and $y$? Or I should list out all the possible events and conclude $f(x,y)\neq f_1(x)f_2(y)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is enough to find one pair $x,y$ with $P(X=x|Y=y) \neq P(X=x)$.

Comment: is it okay to use this way even if $X$ and $Y$ are random variable, not an event?

Answer (score 0):

Both methods are valid, just choose the one which is done easier.  But I’m not sure what you mean by list out all possible events”.

Comment: What i mean is , is it necessary to prove for all set of (x,y)?