# What's $\Pr(X=0|X=Y)$?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables that take values in $\{0,1\}$.

My question is:  how to solve our $\Pr(X=0 | X=Y)$?  We only know that $\Pr(Y=0) = \Pr(Y=1) = 0.5$.

---

My attempt:

$$\begin{split}
\Pr(X=0|X=Y) &= \frac{
\Pr(X=0)
}{
\begin{split}
 &\Pr(X=0,Y=0)\\
+&\Pr(X=1,Y=1)
\end{split}
}\\
&= \frac{
\Pr(X=0)
}{
\begin{split}
 &\Pr(X=0)\Pr(Y=0)\\
+&\Pr(X=1)\Pr(Y=1)
\end{split}
}\\
&= \frac{
\Pr(X=0)
}{
\begin{split}
 &\Pr(X=0)\Pr(Y=0)\\
+&(1-\Pr(X=0))(1-\Pr(Y=0))
\end{split}
}
\end{split}$$

Then, if I try $\Pr(Y=0)=.5$, I get:

$$\begin{split}
\Pr(X=0|X=Y) &= 
\frac{
\Pr(X=0)
}{\Pr(X=0)\times .5 + (1-\Pr(X=0)) \times .5}\\
 &= 
\frac{
\Pr(X=0)
}{\Pr(X=0)\times .5 + (1 \times .5-\Pr(X=0) \times .5)}\\
 &= 
\frac{
\Pr(X=0)
}{\Pr(X=0)\times .5 + .5-\Pr(X=0) \times .5}\\
 &= 
\frac{
\Pr(X=0)
}{.5}\\
 &= 2\Pr(X=0)\\
\end{split}$$

Then, if $\Pr(X=0)=.6$, the answer is $2\times.6 = 1.2 > 1$.  Madness!

---

My attempt *(NEW)*:

$$\begin{split}
\Pr(X=0|X=Y) 
&= \frac{\Pr(X=0,X=Y)}{\Pr(X=Y)} \\
&= \frac{\Pr(X=0)\Pr(X=Y|X=0)}{\Pr(X=Y)} \\
&= \frac{\Pr(X=0)\Pr(X=Y|X=0)}{\Pr(X=0)\Pr(Y=0)+\Pr(X=1)\Pr(Y=1)} \\
&= \frac{\Pr(X=0)\Pr(Y=0)}{\Pr(X=0)\Pr(Y=0)+\Pr(X=1)\Pr(Y=1)} \\
\end{split}$$

Plugging $\Pr(Y=0) = \Pr(Y=1) = .5$:

$$\begin{split}
\Pr(X=0|X=Y) 
&= \frac{.5\Pr(X=0)}{.5\Pr(X=0)+.5\Pr(X=1)} \\
&= \frac{.5\Pr(X=0)}{.5(\Pr(X=0)+\Pr(X=1))} \\
&= \frac{.5\Pr(X=0)}{.5(1)} \\
&= \frac{.5\Pr(X=0)}{.5} \\
&= \Pr(X=0) \\
\end{split}$$

Comment: Recall that $P(A | B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}.$ The problem with your manipulation is that you began with $\frac{P(A)}{P(B)}$: in actuality you should have an additional factor of $0.5$ in the numerator and you should be able to conclude $P(X = 0 | X = Y) = P(X = 0).$ (although this is only true for this particular case)

Comment: @StephenDonovan - Thanks!  Is my new attempt all correct?  I wonder if I accidentally found the right answer by some wrong step in the middle.

Comment: @StephenDonovan - Did I just needlessly prolong it?  E.g. should I have written $\Pr(X=0|X=Y)$ as $\Pr(X=0|Y=0)$ from the start?  :D

Comment: [Two Independent Random Variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2781819)

Comment: It is logical that, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $X$ attaining certain value doesn't depend on $Y$ so you just have to compute $\Bbb P(X=0),$ if I'm not wrong.

Comment: @Spring - but in this case we know that it happened that $X=Y$, and this observation has to be incorporated to update the probabilities.  It became the same as $\Pr(X=0)$ only because we were lucky that $\Pr(Y=0) = 0.5$.

Comment: @caveman The fact that you correctly concluded that $P(X=0|X=Y)=P(X=0)$ means that the event $A=\{X=0\}$ and $B=\{X=Y\}$ are independent and this holds for any value we assign to $P(X=0)$. One can only conclude that there are an infinite number of solutions. We can construct random variablex $X$ an $Y$ that are independent and as such that $P(X=0|X=Y)=.5$ when $P(X=0)=.5$. Similarly can construct $X$ and $Y $ independent with $P(X=0)=.3$ and arrive at $P(X=0|X=Y)=.3$. I might be wrong but more information might be needed.

Comment: @caveman, so, if $Y$ represents the side of a non-symmetrical coin in the second tossing, and $X$ in the first tossing, how does the result of a second tossing affect the first?

Comment: @Spring Consider $P(X=0)=.5$ and $P(Y=0)=.25$. Let $P(Y=0,X=0)=\frac{1}{8}$ and similarly for all remaining combinations. $X$ and $Y$ are independent but $P(X=0|Y=X)=.25\neq .5$. I don't think we can assume $X\perp Y$ implies independence between the two events $\{X=0\}$ and $\{X=Y\}$. But I might be wrong.

Comment: @NoeVidales You are right, the fact that we got $P(X = 0 | X = Y) = P(X = 0)$ here is an artifact of us choosing $Y$ with $P(Y = 0) = 0.5.$ One way to see this is that $P(X = 0 | X=Y) = P(Y = 0 | X = Y)$ (just based off of sample spaces) so again choosing $P(Y = 0) = 0.5$ and leaving $X$ free we would get $P(Y = 0 | X = Y) = P(X = 0) \neq P(Y = 0).$ So we cannot in general conclude that the events are independent. (this also shows how $X = 0 | X = Y$ is different than $X = 0 | Y = 0$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables that take values in
> $\{0,1\}.$
>
> We know that $\Pr(Y=0) = \Pr(Y=1) = 0.5\tag2.$
>
> What is $\Pr(X=0 | X=Y) \;?$

Your new attempt is all good.

Note that armed only with the information in the first line but without statement $(2),$ $X$ and $Y$ attaining the same value, i.e., $\{X=Y\},$ and $\{X=0\}$ are not necessarily independent events. (After all, the probability that $Y$ equals $x$ generally does depend on whether $x$ equals $0.)$ Verify this by setting $P(X=0)P(X=Y)=P(X=0=Y).$

These two events are independent precisely when $\{X=0\}$ is impossible or certain or $Y$ is uniformly distributed. Here, statement $(2)$ informs us of the latter.